# SMD electrolytic capacitor identification

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit

[image]

Anyone happen to know what is the capacitance and voltage reading of this capacitor? The print reads:

```
228
PC
330
4
```

Comment: Most likely 330uF 4V, and based on color, it is most likely a very low-ESR polymer electrolytic type. So you can't replace that with a standard electrolytic. What is that device that has this capacitor and what does the capacitor do in that device?

Comment: It is used in a graphics card. Likely to to with the output interface portion of the card.